# Detect all dependencies of a Windows application

Tags: windows, deployment, dependencies

I am in the process of "detecting" (more like listing down) all of the dependencies of our application.

Currently, I am using depends.exe (Dependency Walker) to detect all of the file dependencies.

I was actually able to get pass all the error messages about missing files and dependencies. However, when launching the app, all I get is a crash without any messages at all.

On a "working" configuration/system, I was able to launch this app successfully. Killing a certain service will produce the "crashing" behavior. This leads me to the conclusion that SOMETHING on this service is needed by the App and this service is a dependency. However, depends.exe will not be able to "detect" this dependency.

My question is: Is there an application that can programmatically detect dependencies such as Database and Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency Walker cannot detect dependency on dynamically loaded DLLs. You could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find which DLLs your program is actually tries to find.

Comment: absolutely procmon is the way to attack this problem.

don't forget it could be relying on registered COM objects and registry entries.

Comment: Don't forget about the "Profile" command in Dependency Walker to see what DLLs loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you define "dependency". You can (using perhaps a hacked version of [fabricate](http://code.google.com/p/fabricate/)), identify the 'files' your application depends on (dlls etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You need PE Explorer and its [Delay Import Viewer](http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_delay-import-viewer.htm) to view the list of the linked delay-load libraries.